# Tengo un error al crear una insercion en un formulario con PHP y Mysql

Tags: php, html, mysql, base-de-datos

tengo un problema al intentar añadir un cliente a la base de datos, estoy probando a ver como va esto pero no entiendo mucho todavia, una ayuda se agradece, el codigo de error que me saca es este:

> Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: mysqli_stmt_close(): Argument #1 ($statement) must be of type mysqli_stmt, bool given in C:\xampp\htdocs\Clientes\crear_cliente.php:42 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\Clientes\crear_cliente.php(42): mysqli_stmt_close(false) #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\Clientes\crear_cliente.php on line 42

Y el codigo es este:

```
<?php
// Include config file
require_once "../config.php";
 
// Define variables and initialize with empty values
$nombre = $apellidos = $fechanac = $fechareg = $nif = $email = $direccion = $ciudad = $provincia = $telefono = $telefono2 = "";
$nombre_err = $apellidos_err = $fechanac_err = $fechareg_err = $nif_err = $email_err = $direccion_err = $ciudad_err = $provincia_err = $telefono_err = $telefono2_err = "";
 
// Processing form data when form is submitted
if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"){
        // Prepare an insert statement
        if(empty($nombre_err) && empty($apellidos_err) && empty($nif_err)){
        $sql = "INSERT INTO clientes (Nombre_cliente, Apellidos_cliente, Fecha_nac_cliente, NIF/NIE_cliente, E-mail_cliente, Direccion_cliente, Ciudad_cliente, Provincia_cliente, Telefono_cliente, Telefono2_cliente) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";

        if($stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, $sql)){
            // Bind variables to the prepared statement as parameters
            mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "sss", $param_nombre, $param_apellidos, $param_fechanac, $param_fechareg, $param_nif, $param_email, $param_direccion, $param_ciudad, $param_provincia, $param_telefono, $param_telefono2);
            
            // Set parameters
            $param_nombre = $nombre;
            $param_apellidos = $apellidos;
            $param_fechanac = $fechanac;
            $param_fechareg = $fechareg;
            $param_nif = $nif;
            $param_email = $email;
            $param_direccion = $direccion;
            $param_ciudad = $ciudad;
            $param_provincia = $provincia;
            $param_telefono = $telefono;
            $param_telefono2 = $telefono2;
            
            // Attempt to execute the prepared statement
            if(mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt)){
                // Records created successfully. Redirect to landing page
                header("location: clientes.php");
                exit();
            } else{
                echo "Algo fallo, intentelo mas tarde." . mysqli_error($link);
            }
        }
        // Close statement
        mysqli_stmt_close($stmt); //línea 42
    }
    // Close connection
    mysqli_close($link);
}
?>
```

Comment: El que dio el voto de cierre, por favor, argumentar por que está cerrando la pregunta, no le veo nada malo como para cerrarla.

Comment: Hola, Bienvenid@ al Sitio, veo que eres nuev@ te recomendaría hacer el [tour] para que conozcas mejor el sitio, He mirado tu post y te comento lo siguiente:, Puedes leer este Articulo [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida, Puedes leer este Articulo [mre], También es importante que sepas que preguntas son mal vistas [help/dont-ask].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Estás cerrando $stmt independientemente de que mysqli_prepare() haya tenido éxito o no. Debes dejar el cierre del statement dentro del if que lo comprueba:

```
if ($stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, $sql)) {
    
    //Aquí haces tus cosas...

    //Y puedes cerrar el statement
    mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
}
//Aquí mysqli_prepare() puede haber fallado,
//en ese caso la instrucción de cerrar el statement te fallará,
//porque recibe bool (false) en vez de un mysqli_stmt.
//mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
```

Deberías ser capaz de depurar este tipo de errores por ti mismo, te está diciendo qué error se está produciendo y dónde, te basta con fijarte un poco o sacar unos mensajes de depurado para darte cuenta de tu descuido. Porque este es sólo el principio, ¿qué tal un else para cuando te falle crear el statement?

Comment: saves de symfony?

Answer (score 0):

Tu problema ocurre en la siguiente seccion:

- Estás asignando el `$stmt` dentro del IF. Por ende, si el IF es FALSO, el $stmt igual, o sea, es un booleano. Un booleano no puede ser el cerrado. Te hacen falta evaluaciones en caso de fallo de la consulta.

  ```
    if($stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, $sql)){
        // Bind variables to the prepared statement as parameters
        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "sss", $param_nombre, $param_apellidos, $param_fechanac, $param_fechareg, $param_nif, $param_email, $param_direccion, $param_ciudad, $param_provincia, $param_telefono, $param_telefono2);

        // Set parameters
        $param_nombre = $nombre;
        $param_apellidos = $apellidos;
        $param_fechanac = $fechanac;
        $param_fechareg = $fechareg;
        $param_nif = $nif;
        $param_email = $email;
        $param_direccion = $direccion;
        $param_ciudad = $ciudad;
        $param_provincia = $provincia;
        $param_telefono = $telefono;
        $param_telefono2 = $telefono2;

        // Attempt to execute the prepared statement
        if(mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt)){
            // Records created successfully. Redirect to landing page
            header("location: clientes.php");
            exit();
        } else{
            echo "Algo fallo, intentelo mas tarde." . mysqli_error($link);
        }
    }
    // Close statement
    mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
  ```

Ahora, lo que debes hacer es evaluar en que casos tu consulta retorna false.